# Soldering station: power confusion

Tags: soldering, watts

i wanted to ask what the different power/watt indictors for a soldering station actually mean in terms of the performance of the station or whether the number is just some marketing term.

1. Some soldering stations have low power itself, but the heater has a higher power. See for example the [Ersa i-Con1](https://www.kurtzersa.com/electronics-production-equipment/soldering-tools-accessories/soldering-desoldering-stations/produkt-details/i-con-1-2.html), wich is a "80 Watt station" with a "150W heater", according to their homepage.
2. Some stations have high power, but the heater has lower power. See for example the [JBC - CD-2BE](https://www.jbctools.com/cd-2be-soldering-station-for-general-purposes-product-1124-category-1-menu-1.html). The homepage says, its transformer has 130 Watts, but the heater only 50 Watts. On some shops the same station is marketted as "75 Watt station", see e.g. [here](https://www.weidinger.eu/shop/loettechnik/jbc/jbc_loet-_und_entloetgeraete/jbc_compact_line/wl34708).
3. Some stations are marketted at 80 Watts, although their power specification lists only 68 Watts, see the [Ersa I-Con Nano](https://www.kurtzersa.de/electronics-production-equipment/loetwerkzeuge-zubehoer/loetstationen-entloetstationen/produkt-details/i-con-nano-1.html). The german website says literally: "This is an 80 Watt station with 68 Watts", both numbers appear on the same page without refering to different parts of the unit.

For me, 1. makes no sense. The iron is capable of 150Watt but can only be supplied with 80 Watts. Also 2. makes no sense, where is the power wasted? And 3. makes no sense either ...

Can someone clarify my confusion?

Comment: I guess the stations can connect to different irons?

Comment: So you would suggest that the minimum of all given powers is the actual power usable? Or is it beneficial that one is larger than the other ... ? But that would indicate that the JBC has a lower power than, e.g. the Ersa. But all tests show that the 50 Watt JBC has a much higher termal power than, e.g. the 80 Watt Ersa.

Comment: You maybe confused by ratings for the power supply vs. the iron wattage itself. Normally the power supply is overrated for long life and/or irons of different wattages that plug into the power supply, which can get a bit expensive. Hakko and Weller are the industry standards.

Answer (score 1):

The Con 1 has a bigger heater for 2 second startup but uses less power for steady use and has power sleep features to extend the tip life.  This is better.
 [image]

[From the JBC "Heating System" page](https://www.jbctools.com/heating-system.html)

Comment: Yep, JBC seems to be the best in current market. I am happy with cheaper Weller WX-1 with WXMP 55-W iron and a bunch of interchangeable tips, RT-1 and RT-7 being my favorites.

Answer (score 1):

The brands you list sell both their Soldering Tools separate from their Stations.

This means in the case of Ersa that you can buy the i-CON 1 station with 80 watts, and use the 150W i-Tool, limited to 80 Watts. But this same i-Tool can be used on the i-CON 2V, which has 120 Watts or the i-CON VARIO 4 with 300 Watts.

The same applies to JBC and other vendors.

80 Watts should be more than enough for most soldering jobs. Unless you're doing aluminum pcb or multi-layer extra thick copper clad. But you'd know 80 Watts is insufficient if you were.